# how to stop the for loop and perform another method then come back to continue with objective-c?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, web-services, for-loop

I am using SOAP WebService and am using a for loop to loop over the accounts i received.

In every loop I call another request to the WebService so what i need is inside the for loop when make the request , go to get the response and then continue the loop.

Here is the code for the for loop:

```
for (A2AWCAccount* account in accountList.Accounts) {
      [_internalAccounts addObject:[[AccountDO alloc] initWithAccountName:[account localizedDescription] AccountNumber:account.Number Balance:[account.CurBal doubleValue] Currency:account.Curr]];

      DataBank* dataBank = [DataBank getInstace];

      A2AService* service = [A2AService service];
      service.logging = YES;

      A2AWCListCard* accountList = [A2AWCListCard alloc];
      accountList.CustMnemonic = dataBank.customerId;
      accountList.SessionID = dataBank.sessionId;
      accountList.AccountNumber = account.Number;
      accountList.Type = @"V";

      // here i make the request
     [service wrListCard:self listCard:accountList];
}
```

and here is the code for the method that get the response

```
- (void) onload:(id)value {
if ([value isKindOfClass:[A2AWCListCard class]]) {
    A2AWCListCard* obj = (A2AWCListCard*) value;
    if (obj.ErrorCode != 0) {
        if (obj.ErrorCode == 109) {
            [self handleSessionError];
            return;
        }else if (obj.ErrorCode == 116)
        {
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Info", @"Info") message:[obj localizedError] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Ok", @"Ok") otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            alert.tag = 5;
            [alert show];
            return;
        }
        [self handleRequestError:[obj localizedError] closeView:YES];
        return;
    }

    for (A2AWCCard* account in obj.Cards) {
        [_cards addObject:[[CardDO alloc] initWithCardNumber:account.CardNo balance:[account.CurBal doubleValue] minimumPayment:account.CardAcc currencyCode:account.Status status:account.Curr cardName:[account localizedDescription] cardNo:account.Number]];
        _totalBalance += [account.CurBal doubleValue];

    }

    [cardsPicker setNeedsDisplay];
    [cardsPicker reloadAllComponents];  

    _servicesInitialized = YES;
}
}
```

The problem happened here is that the loop make it calls N times depend on the number of accounts so for example if there is 3 accounts it makes 3 request and then I waits 3 response so it contribute with each others sometimes because the server is kinda slow.

Anyone help please ??

Comment: Are these calls performed on the main thread?

Comment: i dont know but i think yes its on the main thread ,, because its not set to any other thread

Comment: Won't that block the main (UI) thread for a long period of time?  How is `[service wrListCard:self listCard:accountList];` implemented?

Comment: no it doesn't block it for along period of time and this method is hard to put here how its implemented i used sudzC.com which generate the webservice for me automatically and it makes everything

Comment: Well as long as the request is made in the background, you'll be OK; just because it doesn't block during development (where the server is often on the same network as the client), doesn't mean it won't block "in the wild" (where the client is connected to the internet via 3G).  Knowing how feedback is provided by these methods is crucial to answering your question; it sounds like you need to get the current "state" of the requests into the method that is performing the `for`-loop.

Comment: why not send the entire for operation to a background thread ?
Simply wrap it with a gcd async block


dispatch_queue_t  appSubQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.myapp", NULL);

dispatch_async (appSubQueue , ^{ 
 for () {

 }
});

Comment: Like the comments are suggesting, you really, really need to focus on making this all work with background tasks. You will never be able to guarantee that this will perform well (slow web servers, slow network, slow cellular network, ...)  You should research `NSOperation`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments...you have an architecture issue.

Don't do this:

[image: You are trying to do what I depicted here:]

Instead do this:

[image: What you should do is like so:]

1 So first you know how many accounts, so keep that info.

2 Create a queue and limit it to let's say 3 operations

3 Observe your queue to know when it's done processing the count

4 Now loop your accounts adding operations to your queue

Note: You can use GCD, but this is better for what you need to do

5 You can subclass NSOperation to return info back to your main queue

Note: Instead you could use this method with NSURLConnection

(sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:)

6 In the function observing the queue, when you hit your count...

```
A Kill the queue

B Do something with the returned data, probably in some array
```

Good luck!

Comment: i really appreciate your work , am kinda new to the NSOperationQueue so i initialize it and set the maximum number ,, but after that i dont know what to do , the code is above could you please help me with it !

Comment: I mentioned the following method (sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:) because the second parameter will take the queue you created. Play around with it, it's not that bad once you use it. Oh yeah, same with blocks...you will love them once you get the hang of them.